# Simplifying multiple ifs dealing with flag enum

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have some code like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum someEnumFlag : long
...

if (someFlagEnum)
    if (!foo()) return;
if (someFlagEnum)
    if (!bar()) return;
// repeat similar lines...
```

For each `someFlagEnum`, some method is called and it returns a `bool`. If any of return values is `false`, the entire operation fails. Therefore `return`.

How can I simplify this? I want that "premature return" part intact, so I don't think `foreach` is viable here. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

**Note: This `someFlagEnum` is very large (20+ flags).**

Edited code. Yes, that enum is really `System.Enum`.

Comment: Why would using a `foreach` impact your ability to use the `return` statement and exit early?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is `someFlagEnum` a real `System.Enum` type?

Comment: I think you need a map between your enum and the flags.  Your example is not very clear - you say a method is being called, but your code doesn't show that.  A closer-to-real example would help.

Comment: Edited code. Hopefully my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a lot of these flagenum values and corresponding function calls, you could reduce the code size and execution time using a dictionary lookup as a sparse array:

```
    // set this up in advance of evaluation.  Reuse across multiple evals
    var lookup = new Dictionary<int, Func<bool>>();
    lookup.Add(flag1, () => foo());
    lookup.Add(flag2, () => bar());
    lookup.Add(flag1 | flag2, () => foo() && bar());
    // etc...
```

For each combination of flags, you add a lambda function that calls each of the corresponding functions and returns the logical and of their results, with boolean short circuit evaluation.  It's a little bit cumbersome to build, but the payoff is in the evaluation:

```
    // on evaluation, do this:
    var func = lookup[someFlagEnum];  // all bits considered at the same time
    if (!func())  // all (and only) the corresponding test functions called together
        return;
```

There is a small amount of overhead for the hash lookup and anonymous function call, but if you have a lot of flags that you're testing and calling functions for, I would expect this lookup approach to perform better than piles of if statements or one if statement with a very large expression, and faster than looping through all the bits one at a time.  You'll need to do some performance measurement to see where the tipping point is, but I would expect it could be as low as 6 or 7 flags (iow, lookup may be faster than performing 6 or 7 separate tests)

Comment: If the Enum has flags and there are 20+ Enums, setting up the lookups for the flag combinations is going to be a pita. Great solution otherwise. I was just getting ready to post a solution using reflection, but the strongly typed methods make this far better. Nice job. +1

Comment: For a large number of flag combos, the lookup dictionary could be generated in code to reduce the manual labor of setup.  Instead of having a single lambda func with all the test function calls in one expression, you could break them out and compose them together.  Slightly less efficient at runtime.  Use of expression trees to build the function call expressions would be as efficient at runtime as hand written expressions.

Comment: If it's 20 flags seldom used in combinations, I'd take the PITA and just write the 20ish lines of code to set up the lookup. If all combinations of the 20 flags are possible and need to be represented, I'd take a moment to consider whether I really want to take the memory hit for generating a lookup table with a million entries (2 ^ 20).  If performance trumps memory consumption, go for it.

Comment: One more note: If every combination of those 20 flags is needed, don't use a dictionary, just use an array.  The dictionary is better for the sparse case (20 flags rarely used in combination) but array is better for the dense case. Array indexing is a direct address offset calculation, faster than the dictionary's hash calc and lookup.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (
    (someFlagEnum1 && !foo1()) || 
    (someFlagEnum2 && !foo2()) ||
    (someFlagEnum3 && !foo3()) ||
    (someFlagEnum4 && !bar4()) ||
    (someFlagEnum5 && !bar5()) ||
    (someFlagEnum6 && !bar6()) ||
    (someFlagEnum7 && !bar7()) ||
    (someFlagEnum8 && !bar8())
 )
 {
    return;
 }
```

Simpler and more unreadable! The road to obfuscated C# starts here! :-) :-)

Second solution (C# 4.0, adaptable to other variants):

```
var conditions = new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>[] {
    new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>(() => someFlagEnum.flag1, () => foo1()), 
    new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>(() => someFlagEnum.flag2, () => foo2()), 
    new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>(() => someFlagEnum.flag3, () => foo3()), 
    new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>(() => someFlagEnum.flag4, () => foo4()), 
    new Tuple<Func<bool>, Func<bool>>(() => someFlagEnum.flag5, () => foo5())
}

foreach (var cond in conditions) {
    if (cond.Item1() && !cond.Item2()) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for editing, but I want to see if there are other ways until I accept yours as answer. :)